# Odoo 10 Pos : Could not read card

Tags: odoo-10

when setup odoo pos for using credit card and making payment and the swiping the card on MAGTEK Pos machine i got this error : This can be caused by a badly executed swipe or by not having your keyboard layout set to US QWERTY (not US International).

Answer (score 0):

Change settings of your system and make keyboard layout type as a QWERTY instead of international.